# grails ajax functionality - an "annoying bug"

Tags: javascript, grails

How does one use remoteLink or remoteFunction to invoke an action, and then use what that action produces/returns inside a JavaScript function?  As soon as I put a parameter inside the JavaScript function to call on completion of the action, the function is no longer invoked at all, e.g.:

```
    onComplete: 'processUpdate(e);'    --or--

    after: 'processAfter(e)'
```

then, the Javascript function is no longer called at all.  Fyi: whole line of code is:

```
<g:select name="week" from="${strategyInstance.constraints.week.inList}" value="${strategyInstance?.week}" valueMessagePrefix="strategy.week" noSelection="['': '']"
   onchange="${remoteFunction(action: 'produceUpdate', params: '\'update=\' + this.value', onComplete:'processUpdate(e);', before:  'alert("doing before")', after: 'processAfter(e)')}"/>
```

If I remove the parameter "e" out of the Javascript function name, i.e.:

```
 onComplete: 'processUpdate();'
```

then it calls the function.  If I declare the function:

```
  function processUpdate(e) {
   alert('processUpdate: ' +e)
  }
```

it invokes the function but alerts me with:

```
     processUpdate: undefined
```

So, how does one with Grails get results produced by actions into a Javascript function that  one can then work on/with?

Comment: Note this doesn't work in either Grails 1.3.7 or Grails 2.0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a very annoying bug in xml-parsing mechanism: As soon as you define an attribute within a grails-tag, which contains double-quotes, and the tag itself uses double quotes, the complete attribute definition is ignored. Your alert uses double quotes. Try:

```
<g:select name="week" from="${strategyInstance.constraints.week.inList}" 
  value="${strategyInstance?.week}" 
  valueMessagePrefix="strategy.week" 
  noSelection="['': '']"
  onchange="${remoteFunction(
      action: 'produceUpdate', 
      params: '\'update=\' + this.value', 
      onComplete:'processUpdate(e);', 
      before:  'alert(\'doing before\')', 
      after: 'processAfter(e)')}"/>
```

onComplete is called independent of whether the AJAX call is fine or not (so success and failure). If you want to access the result in success case use `onSuccess` with parameter `data`:

```
<g:select name="week" from="${strategyInstance.constraints.week.inList}" 
  value="${strategyInstance?.week}" 
  valueMessagePrefix="strategy.week" 
  noSelection="['': '']"
  onchange="${remoteFunction(
      action: 'produceUpdate', 
      params: '\'update=\' + this.value', 
      onSuccess: 'processUpdate(data);', 
      before:  'alert(\'doing before\')', 
      after: 'processAfter(e)')}"/>
```

Comment: Thank you.  "a very annoying bug" indeed! I've tried all sorts of combos in Grails 1.3.7 and Grails 2.0, probably had double quotes somewhere in all of them, as I could never get it to work.  Do you think the Grails folks are aware of this?

Comment: Just a quick follow-up question if I may, on sending a map as a result back to a Javascript function.  Is there a nice/easy way to parse a grails map inside a Javascript function that you know of?

Comment: In the remote action convert your result map to JSON using: `render (resultMap as JSON)`. `data` is immediately a javascript object then. You can debug this using `console.log(data)` on the JS-side and in combination with firebug. And regarding the bug: http://jira.grails.org/browse/GRAILS-1973?page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels%3Aall-tabpanel. Unfortunately it wasn't considered as "fix-worth", which is very sad.

Comment: I haven't used JSON, thanks very much for that (overall pointer).  I looked at the jira you referened, and it looked like Burt B. is working on it even as of August 2011, and then it has a resolution: fixed status.  Where did you see the "fix-worth" ... I searched on page but didn't find it.

Comment: Sorry, its just my bad english. All i wanted to say is, that they closed this issue with the comment "just use single quotes" which is a very bad work around. Check the issue state.

Comment: I see, thanks.  It looks like Graeme Rocher made the comment you said, but Burt Beckwith has been working on ever since, which is good.  It is a significant issue (wasted lots of my time), and appreciate your help. Semi-related, have you by chance tried this plugin: http://grails.org/plugin/javascript-converter?